# Swapping dependencies with Snap

Tags: haskell, dependencies, haskell-snap-framework

I started working on a new snap barebones project with stack. When I stack init, it resolves to an older ghc compiler. When I upgraded the compiler, I got errors for the MonadCatchIO-transformer dependency. I went [MonadCatchIO docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadCatchIO-transformers) they say it is deprecated for [exceptions library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions). So I replaced the dependency in my cabal file and was able to get my project to build and run hello world.

I want to know if I should expect errors later on in the Snap framework if/when I get more complex than a hello world project.

Why was MonadCatchIO-transformer part of the barebones template if it isn't necessary and several years obsolete.

Comment: Hurt you later?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here. The title and first paragraph of the question seems to imply you are running into issues with dependencies of your project. But then you state you've solved this problem and ask a different (very vague) question about whether a particular library will somehow be harmful to your project.

Comment: I tried revamping my question. I hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

After going through the git repository for snap-templates, I found that the [template file](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-templates/blob/master/project_template/barebones/foo.cabal) doesn't even reference a MonadCatchIO-transformers. It seems whatever I downloaded with cabal install snap-templates isn't the current source code.

I have asked them to update hackage in an issue request.